# PHPUnit mocking object that is the same type as the SUT and is a property of the SUT

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I have a class called `TestClass` which has a property called `parent`. The `parent` property is the same type as the `TestClass`.
Show below is a portion of the `TestClass` I am trying to test.

```
class TestClass
{
    /**
     * @param array $parentIds
     * @return ApiLock[]
     */
    protected function getParentLocks(array $parentIds)
    {
        if ($this->getParent()) {
            $id = array_pop($parentIds);
            return $this->getParent()->getLocks($id, $parentIds);
        }

        return [];
    }

    /**
     * @param array $ids
     * @return ApiLock[]
     */
    protected function getLocks($id, array $ids)
    {
        $locks = $this->getParentLocks($ids);

        if ($this->config->getLockName()) {
            $locks[] = new ApiLock($this->config->getLockName() . '.' . $id, $this->config->getLockWait());
        }

        return $locks;
    }

}
```

The method `getLocks` calls the `getParentLocks` method. To test this class, I have mocked `TestClass` object and set as the parent of the SUT. Something similar to this.

```
$apiLock = $this->getMockBuilder(ApiLock::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
        $parent = $this->getMockBuilder(TestClass::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $parent->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getLocks')
            ->will($this->returnValue([$apiLock]));

        $testClass->setParent($parent);
```

But when i run the tests , the method `setLocks` on the `parent` object will not return the stubbed value but will actually call the `setLocks` method on the parent object and the test fails. May be I am not seeing something obvious.
The stubbed method should be called instead of the real method on the parent object.
Please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what mocking / testing framework you're using. but I think it should have a `when()` method so the Mock knows for which method call it should return what stubbed data. At the moment as you say, your stub isn't called _or_ your Mock is actually acting as a Spy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem doesn't have anything to do with the parent-child relation.

You should define which methods you want to mock:

```
    $parent = $this->getMockBuilder(TestClass::class)
        ->setMethods(['setLocks', 'getLocks'])
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
```

Methods which are not mocked will be called regularly, and your expectations are ignored. You are probably using PHPUnit 4, because in PHPUnit 5 you would see in a warning that you defined an expectation for a method that is not mocked.

---

**Update:** It's true that if you don't call `setMethods()`, all methods should be mocked, but this only applies to **public non-abstract methods**.

This is the code in [PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Generator](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/blob/master/src/Framework/MockObject/Generator.php#L1246-L1258) that automatically determines methods to be mocked:

```
public function getClassMethods($className)
{
    $class   = new ReflectionClass($className);
    $methods = [];
    foreach ($class->getMethods() as $method) {
        if ($method->isPublic() || $method->isAbstract()) {
            $methods[] = $method->getName();
        }
    }
    return $methods;
}
```

So you can mock protected methods (and also nonexistent methods that would trigger `__call()`), but other than public methods, you need to specify them explicitly.

Comment: thanks. that solved it. However, I thought that if setMethods was not used, all methods could be mocked.

Comment: @ShikharSubedi I think, this is only true for **public** methods